# не получается использовать цепочки js, как правильно решить задачу?

Tags: javascript

Этот массив объектов мы будем передавать в параметр users при вызове функции из задания.

```
[
  {
    name: "Moore Hensley",
    email: "moorehensley@indexia.com",
    eyeColor: "blue",
    friends: ["Sharron Pace"],
    isActive: false,
    balance: 2811,
    gender: "male"
  },
  {
    name: "Sharlene Bush",
    email: "sharlenebush@tubesys.com",
    eyeColor: "blue",
    friends: ["Briana Decker", "Sharron Pace"],
    isActive: true,
    balance: 3821,
    gender: "female"
  },
  {
    name: "Ross Vazquez",
    email: "rossvazquez@xinware.com",
    eyeColor: "green",
    friends: ["Marilyn Mcintosh", "Padilla Garrison", "Naomi Buckner"],
    isActive: false,
    balance: 3793,
    gender: "male"
  },
  {
    name: "Elma Head",
    email: "elmahead@omatom.com",
    eyeColor: "green",
    friends: ["Goldie Gentry", "Aisha Tran"],
    isActive: true,
    balance: 2278,
    gender: "female"
  },
  {
    name: "Carey Barr",
    email: "careybarr@nurali.com",
    eyeColor: "blue",
    friends: ["Jordan Sampson", "Eddie Strong", "Adrian Cross"],
    isActive: true,
    balance: 3951,
    gender: "male"
  },
  {
    name: "Blackburn Dotson",
    email: "blackburndotson@furnigeer.com",
    eyeColor: "brown",
    friends: ["Jacklyn Lucas", "Linda Chapman", "Adrian Cross", "Solomon Fokes"],
    isActive: false,
    balance: 1498,
    gender: "male"
  },
  {
    name: "Sheree Anthony",
    email: "shereeanthony@kog.com",
    eyeColor: "brown",
    friends: ["Goldie Gentry", "Briana Decker"],
    isActive: true,
    balance: 2764,
    gender: "female"
  }
]
```

Моя попытка решить:

```js
const users = [{
    name: "Moore Hensley",
    email: "moorehensley@indexia.com",
    eyeColor: "blue",
    friends: ["Sharron Pace"],
    isActive: false,
    balance: 2811,
    gender: "male"
  },
  {
    name: "Sharlene Bush",
    email: "sharlenebush@tubesys.com",
    eyeColor: "blue",
    friends: ["Briana Decker", "Sharron Pace"],
    isActive: true,
    balance: 3821,
    gender: "female"
  },
  {
    name: "Ross Vazquez",
    email: "rossvazquez@xinware.com",
    eyeColor: "green",
    friends: ["Marilyn Mcintosh", "Padilla Garrison", "Naomi Buckner"],
    isActive: false,
    balance: 3793,
    gender: "male"
  },
  {
    name: "Elma Head",
    email: "elmahead@omatom.com",
    eyeColor: "green",
    friends: ["Goldie Gentry", "Aisha Tran"],
    isActive: true,
    balance: 2278,
    gender: "female"
  },
  {
    name: "Carey Barr",
    email: "careybarr@nurali.com",
    eyeColor: "blue",
    friends: ["Jordan Sampson", "Eddie Strong", "Adrian Cross"],
    isActive: true,
    balance: 3951,
    gender: "male"
  },
  {
    name: "Blackburn Dotson",
    email: "blackburndotson@furnigeer.com",
    eyeColor: "brown",
    friends: ["Jacklyn Lucas", "Linda Chapman", "Adrian Cross", "Solomon Fokes"],
    isActive: false,
    balance: 1498,
    gender: "male"
  },
  {
    name: "Sheree Anthony",
    email: "shereeanthony@kog.com",
    eyeColor: "brown",
    friends: ["Goldie Gentry", "Briana Decker"],
    isActive: true,
    balance: 2764,
    gender: "female"
  }
];

const getNamesSortedByFriendCount = users => {
  let newArray = users.filter(user => user.name)
    .map(user => user.friends)
    .sort((a, b) => a.friends - b.friends);

  return newArray;
};

console.log(getNamesSortedByFriendCount(users));
```

вывод ошибок в системе:
В теле функции используется цепочка методов

Вызов функции с указанным массивом пользователей возвращает массив `['Moore Hensley', 'Sharlene Bush', 'Elma Head', 'Sheree Anthony', 'Ross Vazquez', 'Carey Barr', 'Blackburn Dotson']`

Вызов функции со случайными, но валидными аргументами, возвращает правильное значение

Задание:

> Дополни функцию `getNamesSortedByFriendCount(users)` так, чтобы она возвращала массив имён пользователей отсортированный по возрастанию количества их друзей (свойство friends).

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: Что конкретно не получается? Вот метод для сортировки массивов sort https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: не получается корректно использовать цепочки методов

Comment: @AndreyIvanovichGladkovski Покажите ваши старания

Answer (score 1):

Решение задачи:

```js
const users = [
  {
    name: "Moore Hensley",
    email: "moorehensley@indexia.com",
    eyeColor: "blue",
    friends: ["Sharron Pace"],
    isActive: false,
    balance: 2811,
    gender: "male"
  },
  {
    name: "Sharlene Bush",
    email: "sharlenebush@tubesys.com",
    eyeColor: "blue",
    friends: ["Briana Decker", "Sharron Pace"],
    isActive: true,
    balance: 3821,
    gender: "female"
  },
  {
    name: "Ross Vazquez",
    email: "rossvazquez@xinware.com",
    eyeColor: "green",
    friends: ["Marilyn Mcintosh", "Padilla Garrison", "Naomi Buckner"],
    isActive: false,
    balance: 3793,
    gender: "male"
  },
  {
    name: "Elma Head",
    email: "elmahead@omatom.com",
    eyeColor: "green",
    friends: ["Goldie Gentry", "Aisha Tran"],
    isActive: true,
    balance: 2278,
    gender: "female"
  },
  {
    name: "Carey Barr",
    email: "careybarr@nurali.com",
    eyeColor: "blue",
    friends: ["Jordan Sampson", "Eddie Strong", "Adrian Cross"],
    isActive: true,
    balance: 3951,
    gender: "male"
  },
  {
    name: "Blackburn Dotson",
    email: "blackburndotson@furnigeer.com",
    eyeColor: "brown",
    friends: ["Jacklyn Lucas", "Linda Chapman", "Adrian Cross", "Solomon Fokes"],
    isActive: false,
    balance: 1498,
    gender: "male"
  },
  {
    name: "Sheree Anthony",
    email: "shereeanthony@kog.com",
    eyeColor: "brown",
    friends: ["Goldie Gentry", "Briana Decker"],
    isActive: true,
    balance: 2764,
    gender: "female"
  }
]

const getNamesSortedByFriendCount = users => {
  let newArray = users
    .map(user => user)
    .sort((a, b) => a.friends.length - b.friends.length)
    .map(user => user.name);

  return newArray;
};

console.log(getNamesSortedByFriendCount(users));
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Это ответ на ваш вопрос или это ответ на мой вопрос? Если это ответ на мой вопрос, то пожалуйста перенсите этот код в текст вопроса, нажав на кнопку Править под вашим вопросом. А ещё лучше нажмите на Править под вопросом и в редакторе вопроса нажмите CTRL+M и вставьте ваш код туда. Так мы сможем запускать ваш код и видеть результаты, главное перед вставкой в сообщение убедитесь что код работает без ошибок

Comment: Первый метод map вовсе не нужен здесь. Он здесь не делает вообще ничего

Comment: Кстати это `.map(user => user)` можно заменить на `[...users]`. По сути будет одинаково, просто `map` используется, чтобы получить пробразованные элементы массива, потому если вы с ними ничего не делаете, то лучше так не делать

Comment: @HTOHOT Вы ошибаетесь. Он тут нужен, чтобы не мутировать массив при сортировке